# Syntax to add dynamic parameter in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need syntax help here in react js,

I wish to achieve something like this in the path

```
http://localhost:3000/verify-email?key=ffdffae0237c43e6572bca3a3867eda1&eid=c2Frc2hpN0BnbWFpbC5jb20=
```

The following code doesn't work

```
<Route name="businessInformation" exact path="/verify-email?key=:someRandomKey&eid=:someRandomKey"> //Need help here
```

Although, this works for `http://localhost:3000/verify-email/:key/:eid`

```
 <Route name="businessInformation" exact path="/verify-email/key/eid">
```

How shall I append such string values so that it understands?

Comment: Because if you want to pass a param to path is simply write `/:paramName`. In your code you also write its value. Please check its documentation here : https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string

Comment: I want to achieve something like this instead /verify-email?key=:someRandomKey&eid=:someRandomEmailKey
how can I do that?  where dynamic values are someRandomKey and someRandomEmailKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the question is **very unclear**, for the sake of brevity let's assume that you want to **read** a query string. The route for this would simply look like:

```
<Route
    name="businessInformation"
    exact path="/verify-email"
    render={props => <Example {...props}>}
/>
```

and the component which would need to read the query string would look like:

```
const Example = () => {
    const { key, eid } =  new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    
    return (
        <span>{`key is ${key} and id is ${eid}`}</span>
    )
}
```

And in case you wanting to navigate to such a route, it would be:

```
<Link to={`/verify-email?key${key}&eid=${id}`}/>
```

Comment: what you wrote in <Link/> I wish similar code in <Route exact path/>
Is there a way to do that directly without using <Link to/>

Comment: Why, there's no use-case for it? The route with path "/verify-email" is already capable of reading all the query params.

Comment: Thanks. Found the value in props.location.search. Understood your answer and concept by practically writing your answer in my code!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: hey! getting unidentified on <span>{`key is ${key} and id is ${eid}`}</span> on setting     const { key, eid } =  new URLSearchParams(window.location.search) but in console, getting window.location.search correct query value

Comment: Maybe my desctructuring is a bit off. Try to declare the query as a constant, and then log it to check what is the shape of the query: `const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is query string

> "?var1=val&var2=val2"

And, this is URL parameters

> /api/:param1/edit

To achieve query string with dynamic values, I would suggest to use template literats

```
const someRandomKey = "<random_key>"; // Either hard-code any value or read from a state / props. 
const someRandomId = "<random_id>";
<Route name="businessInformation" exact path=`/verify-email?key=${someRandomKey}&eid=${someRandomKey}`>
```

Comment: These values can't  be hardcoded or come from a state.
In app.js, I wish to hit the url:
http://localhost:3000/verify-email?key=ffdffae0237c43e6572bca3a3867eda1&eid=c2Frc2hpN0BnbWFpbC5jb20=
where key and eid are dynamic values. 
This link will be coming from user's email to verify. 
How shall I route this in app.js?